# How do you convey the sentiment "not safe for work" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, jerga-internet

How do you convey the sentiment "not safe for work" in Spanish, and is there an acronym for the phrase (like 'nsfw')?  I'm looking for a word, phrase or acronym that communicates any of the spirit of that phrase in English, be it the playfully impish tone, or the HR manager one.

*Update*: I'm not really sure where to begin researching this -- I welcome suggestions on where to look for equivalent internet slang translations

Comment: Note _Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service_. Could you indicate what was your research prior to ask the question? Thanks and welcome to [spanish.se]!

Comment: It is the first time I see that acronym and I could not think of a translation for 'Not situable for work'. As stated on his spanish version on wikipedia "no es seguro/apropiado para el trabajo", but I dare the 99% of spanish people will not understand: NSPT or NAPT.

Comment: I agree with AlexBcn. The expression nsfw doesn't exist in Spanish, so you have to go with some literal translation. I don't think "seguro" is the best option because it would be conflated with the idea of safety in the workplace. "Apropiado" or "adecuado" are better options. Other more general alternatives would be "material sensible" or "material delicado".

Comment: In the context in which this is used, you would probably use the English term. It is like using "lol": there is not direct Spanish translations, so young people use the original term.

Comment: Do you mean NSFW in the literal sense of _you could get hurt_ or NSFW in the internet sense of _not something you would like your boss to catch you watching while at work_? Anyway, I don't think there is an acronym. Young ant techie people will likely understand **NSFW**, especially in the second sense. _Cuidado_, _Peligro_, _Advertencia_ could work (Warning, danger, caution: mainly in the literal sense, but _advertencia_ could be a not-so-obvious way of stating the other alternative). Something like _imágenes explícitas_ could do the job more clearly in the second sense.

Answer (score 3):

in my opinion this concept does not have a clear translation in Spanish, I have never heard of any relevant expression in Spain, however thinking about it I would propose:

> contenido no apropiado

as non-literal translation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's about exactly for `Not suitable for work`, but, in spanish, is common says `No es apto para trabajar`, that's mean that context is no good for work, is insecure or something else, or `No está habilitado para trabajar`, that means that context isn't enabled or hasn't the good contidions for work.

`Suitable`, in spanish, have many means that we can consider as synonyms between, and the mainly mean is appropiate, so, we can think that this phrase can tranlaste as `No apropiado para trabar`, or something phrases like this.

In the case of the sentence is a warning, i mean, have the intention of warn about something, you can use `No apto para trabajo, for example, for nudity`No apto para ser visto, it depends to the verb, the common use is verb as noun, some like it, i forget this time tense name or use name.You can add some other tense for explain why you warn about these something.

In this case, in spanish, doesn't exist a acronym for this, but if you want consider, you could use `NAPT`, in ther most of cases; but, i add here, in spanish use acronyms for this kind of sentences isn't common use and could be represent a problem in speak time.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking. To my understanding, he is looking for a text to put next to a link that may contain some content that you shouldn't open if you are in your workplace, eg, some nudity. With _no es apto para trabajar_ you define the person, whereas we want to define the content.

Comment: Ok man, so, you can use `No apto para trabajo`, for example, for nudity `No apto para ser visto`, it depends to the verb, the common use is verb as noun, some like it, i forget this time tense name or use name. Sorry.

Comment: @SalahAdDin I suggest you to edit that into the answer

Comment: Will be good add that for this type of tenses in spanish we haven't a well knowed slangs variations?